# Randomly replace elements in matrix with a clumpy or aggregated method

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, replace

in the MATLAB code below, the matrix *B* is created from matrix *A* by randomly replacing a portion of its elements (`empty_x`) with *6*.  Instead of replacing the values of `empty_x` elements randomly throughout the matrix, how could I keep them clumped (but still random placement of the clump)?

That is I want all of the *6*-value elements to be neighboring. If it easiest to replace `empty_x` elements a the square matrix *A* with smaller, subset-ed square matrix (size `empty_x`) to create matrix *B* then that would be okay.  It would be cool, but not necessary, to have the clumps that were not always square matrices (i.e heterogeneity).

I would appreciate some ideas on how to accomplish this task.

Cheers.

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5; 5 4 3 2 1; 1 4 3 2 5; 4 3 2 1 5; 2 1 3 5 4];
B = A;
nA = numel(A);
empty_x = randi(10);
B(randperm(nA,(empty_x))) = 6;
```

Comment: So you've got a square matrix, and you want some random square subset of that matrix to be replaced with 6's?  Is that the problem?  I'm not sure what you mean by 'clumped'

Comment: @NatoSaichek That would work. I was using clumped to mean that the elements with *6's* would touch each other as in a subset square matrix, or some other shape.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html)

Comment: @nofunsally What other constraints are you envisioning? Does every matrix need to have the same number of 6s inserted? Do the clumps need to be uniformly distributed throughout the matrix? Can they touch?

Comment: @jerad For any given simulation the number of 6's to be inserted can be the same.  Clumps do not need to be uniformly distributed. @bonCodigo I am looking at MATLAB's `datasample` now.  Thanks.

Comment: I am unsure on how to implement `datasample` to achieve the task above.  Suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be the following:

```
1) Generate a single random number (uniform distribution)  
     on the interval `[1 numel(A)]`. Use this as the linear index  
     of a seed for your clump.  

while clump_size < desired_clump_size     
    2) Generate a list of all positions in the matrix adjacent to  
         (but not already included in) the existing clump.  
    3) Randomly select one of these indices  
    4) Grow the clump by placing an element in this position.  
end
```

I'm not going to write the code; it shouldn't be difficult to implement, particularly if this piece of code isn't a performance bottleneck in your overall project.

EDIT: Since you gave it a try yourself, here's some code:

```
desired_clump = 5;
matrix_size = 5;
A = zeros(matrix_size);
[C,R]=meshgrid(1:size(A,1), (1:size(A,2))'); %'# row and column numbers for each element

seed = ceil(rand(1)*numel(A));
#% I would have used randi(1) but octave online utility doesn't have it
A(seed) = 1; #% initialize a clump
clump_size = 1;

while clump_size < desired_clump
    CI = A==1; #% logical index of current clump
    CR = reshape(R(CI),1,1,[]); #% 1x1xN index of row values of current clump
    CC = reshape(C(CI),1,1,[]); #% 1x1xN index of col values of current clump
    ADJ = sum(bsxfun(@(x,y)abs(x-y),R,CR)<=1 & bsxfun(@(x,y)abs(x-y),C,CC)<=1, 3)>0 & ~A;
    #% ADJ is the indices of the elements adjacent to the current clump
    B=A; #% for display purposes only
    B(ADJ)=2;
    disp(B)
    disp(' ')
    POS = find(ADJ); #% linear indices of the adjacent elements
    IND = ceil(rand(1)*numel(POS)); #% random index into POS vector
    A(POS(IND))=1; #% grow the clump
    clump_size = clump_size+1;
end
disp(A);
```

Output:
`1` indicates elements in the clump; `2` means eligible for clump expansion

```
iteration 1:
   0   0   2   1   2
   0   0   2   2   2
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
iteration 2: 
   0   0   2   1   2
   0   0   2   1   2
   0   0   2   2   2
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
iteration 3: 
   0   0   2   1   2
   0   0   2   1   2
   0   0   2   1   2
   0   0   2   2   2
   0   0   0   0   0
iteration 4: 
   0   0   2   1   1
   0   0   2   1   2
   0   0   2   1   2
   0   0   2   2   2
   0   0   0   0   0

Final clump:
   0   0   0   1   1
   0   0   1   1   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
```

Generating a single random number each time shouldn't be all that slow.  There are also undoubtedly ways to speed it up if it is truly a bottleneck.  Hopefully this example can get you a little further though.

Comment: I've edited to show how I'd go about it.  I see your current issue is with the speed of random number generation.  I'd be curious to know if this works better.  Depending on the size of your matrix and clump, it may be better to swap the line with the `bsxfun`s for a loop (loops aren't horrible anymore, generally - and it would save on memory if you're working with large matrices).

Comment: It wasn't random number generation, my code was otherwise flawed. It gets stuck (often) when looking for a non-6 neighbor.

Comment: The above code works great, I need to learn more about indexing I gather as a lot of the above is still _magic_ too me (even with the comments).  I'll need to read up on these procedures. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Using some of the tips above I constructed the code below.  It works fine for smaller sizes of *A*, but it is incredibly slow when *A* is large.  Thanks for the guidance.

```
clear all
A = zeros(40,40);
[M N] = size(A);
B = A;
nA = numel(A);
per_clump = 10;
dClump = nA*(per_clump/100);
seed = randi(nA);
clumpers = zeros(8,1);
new_seed = seed;
counter = 0;
while counter < dClump; % size of clump
    seed = new_seed;

    for iSize = seed; % find adjacent elements

        west = iSize - M;
        if west < 1
            west = iSize; % the boundary is not periodic
        end;

        east = iSize + M;
        if east > nA
            east = iSize;
        end; %

        north = iSize - 1;
        if north < 1
            north = iSize;
        end; %

        south = iSize + 1;
        if south > nA
            south = iSize;
        end; %

        nwest = iSize - M - 1;
        if nwest < 1
            nwest = iSize;
        end; %

        neast = iSize + M - 1;
        if neast > nA
            neast = iSize;
        end; %

        swest = iSize - M + 1;
        if swest < 1
            swest = iSize;
        end; %

        seast = iSize + M + 1;
        if seast > nA
            seast = iSize;
        end; %

        clumpers = [(west) (east) (north) (south) (nwest) (neast) (seast) (swest)]; % index of adjacent elements
        %new_seed = randsample(clumpers,1); % pick one, really slow

        z = randperm(size(clumpers,2)); % this also really slow
        new_clumpers = clumpers(z);
        new_seed = new_clumpers(randi(8));

        if B(new_seed) == 6;
            %B(new_seed) = B(seed);
            new_seed = seed;
            counter = counter;
        else
            B(new_seed) = 6;
            counter = counter+1;
        end;
    end; %end adj element
end; % end clump size
```

Comment: The problem with the above code is that is becomes increasingly likely as the clump size grows, that it will not find a spot that is suitable (e.g. ~= 6) to replace itself